# Laravel - Eloquent where with array

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I'm trying to execute this query according to the documentation but its returning the error `array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

```
 $imagessize = $galleryObj->photos->where([
                ['gallery_id','=', $gallery->id],
                ['delete','=',0],
            ])->sum('filesize');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `where` method does not accept arrays, if you want that you should use the **whereIn** method:

> The `whereIn` method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array:

For example:

```
users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                ->get();
```

This will return the users with id 1,2 and 3.

But in your case i dont think you need that. Try this instead:

```
$imagessize = $galleryObj->photos->where('gallery_id',$gallery->id)->where('delete', 0)->sum('filesize');
```

Comment: It is not true that there where clause can't accept an array.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can parse an array to the where method in Laravel Eloquent. This is directly referred to in the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses).

Using syntax below certainly works:

```
$where=array();
$where[] = ['field_a', '=', 'a'];
$where[] = ['field_b', '=', 'test'];
$results = DB::table('your_table')->where($where)->get();
```

or

```
$where=array();
$where[] = ['field_a', '=', 'a'];
$where[] = ['field_b', '=', 'test'];
$results = YourModelName::where($where)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

$posts = Post::whereIn('collection_name', ["games", "sports","science"])->get();